# NestJs GraphQL : Unable To set and Get Cookie

Tags: cookies, graphql, nestjs, apollo

I am working on nestJS Graphql Project , and the problem is that when i send the cookie it is not setting on client and if i manually put the cookie it cant read also , but the thing that amazing me is when i login on sever by graphql playground it is setting the data and working smoothly and also it is showing that when i check login from client it is logged In

My Codes

**main.ts**

> ```
> // setting cookie parser
>  app.use(cookieParser());
>
>  // cors origin
>  app.enableCors({
>   origin:true,
>   credentials:true
>  })
> ```

**app.module.ts**

> ````
>  GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
>     driver: ApolloDriver,
>      
>      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
>      context: ({ req , res }) => ({ req, res }),
>      playground:{
>        settings: {
>          'request.credentials': 'include',
>        },
>      },
>      cors: {
>        credentials: true,
>        origin: true
>      }
>   
>    }),```
> ````

**login.resolver.ts**

> ````
> context.res.cookie('__user', val.token, {
>            httpOnly: true,
>            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
>            sameSite: 'none',
>            secure: true,
>        });```
> ````

**checkLogin.service.ts**

> `const cookieValue = context.req.cookies['__user']`

Comment: try setting the domain as well in the cookie options (where you set httpOnly, maxAge, etc...)